# download image with .php url python

Tags: php, python, image

I am trying to write a code that could solve a maze printed in an image
(the maze is created randomly each time).

This image is on internet and i need to solve the maze fast so I would like either to download the image and read it from my computer (may be slower) or to get the datas of this image directly from intenet.
The thing is that the image doesn't have an URL ending with .jpg or .png but with .php (https://www.newbiecontest.org/epreuves/prog/progshort.php). I assume that the real URL from the image must be hidden but i can't figure how to get it, I just know that this is a .png file.
So I tried my 2 solutions but when I try to download the image with urllib.urlretrieve() I can't open the image and when I get datas of the page with urllib I get strange non-ASCII characters. May you help me to get either datas or download the image please (not solving the maze for me).
Thank you and sorry for my english.

**EDIT**:
I tried to add the content-type of image but it still doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
import urllib2, urllib, re

def connexion(url):
    user_agent = 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0'
    Referer = 'https://www.newbiecontest.org/index.php?page=epreuve&no=218'
    Cookie = 'PHPSESSID=blablabla'
    Content_Type = "image/png"


    headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent,
               'Referer': Referer,
               'Cookie': Cookie,
               'Content-Type': Content_Type
              }


    req = urllib2.Request(url, None, headers)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    page = response.read()
    print page
    response.close()

connexion("https://www.newbiecontest.org/epreuves/prog/progshort.php")
```

And here is the result:

ëPNG

IHDR        -r  WIDATx£Ý¦╦N#1ð0Ô Ö┘▄┼ÓAÃ»
:gçÞ©╚òU▒█~<   Ço¢5?||<▀Í█ºÍåÜj^█ÿÚıîà´hßvH ¥;9Ë‗¥O╬É?½éW'┬ !▀ð²╩f_æ4TO´╗©oß█_°w¯;ÍþÖ¹¯{mƒæB äB V╬@ÀMÎ(¥ï▄ÀqÒÏõ²▒Þã┬o5ûÎFaÇaÇøü^xq█ÅSËÖ}ïÓã¥¸"▀=[ä┐­3┘02ä0─{ Î3Õ╚¥ZÝÏ‗´~╦Î!¤¶jÞFÃ║▒░W3Ñ¨ðG┼╚ !

any idea ?

Comment: For starters, that URL appears to require a login. That's likely your first issue. Non-ASCII is expected in an image file, it's a binary format.

Comment: The login is not a problem, I can succesfully access to that URL (by passing cookie in the headers request), so is there a way to change the text format I get when printing the page data's  into binary format ? (perhaps in numbers corresponding to pixel's values ?). thx for your answer btw

Comment: You need to pass on the `Content-Type` header from the response. Will be something like `Content-Type: image/jpg`.